# JDBC - Can I do selects with other operations as one even with autoCommit on?

Tags: java, jdbc

The javadocs for [Connection#setAutoCommit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit%28boolean%29) read as follows, bolding mine:

> Sets this connection's auto-commit
>   mode to the given state. **If a
>   connection is in auto-commit mode,
>   then all its SQL statements will be
>   executed and committed as individual
>   transactions**. Otherwise, its SQL
>   statements are grouped into
>   transactions that are terminated by a
>   call to either the method commit or
>   the method rollback. By default, new
>   connections are in auto-commit mode.
>
> **The commit occurs when the statement
>   completes.** The time when the statement
>   completes depends on the type of SQL
>   Statement:
>
> - For DML statements, such as Insert, Update or Delete, and DDL statements,
>     the statement is complete as soon as
>     it has finished executing.
> - **For Select statements, the statement is complete when the associated result
>     set is closed.**
> - For CallableStatement objects or for statements that return multiple
>     results, the statement is complete
>     when all of the associated result sets
>     have been closed, and all update
>     counts and output parameters have been
>     retrieved.

Does this mean that when autoCommit is on (as it pretty much always should be), if I select a row out of a table, that my Connection object or whatever will be holding a lock on that row/table until the ResultSet is closed?

If so, does that mean that I can select a row, and if I am satisfied by the value of a column, update the row all as one atomic action, as long as I don't close the ResultSet until after the update?

Comment: `when autoCommit is on (as it pretty much always should be)` This is a very bad assumption... How would you roll back an operation if something went wrong afterwards in the application for example?

Comment: But the update will have its transaction of its own and it will commit when the update is completed

Comment: I realise that, but will the select be holding a lock on the row in the mean-time, guaranteeing that I am updating the row as it appears in the select?

Comment: That behaviour is *highly* database dependent. Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: Im using H2, but if its database dependant then it seems the safe answer is no.